# Unexpected results from NSUserDefaults boolForKey

Tags: iphone

After uninstalling an application completely from the device and then loading it in the debugger, I am attempting in a setup method to load a flag using boolForKey. The first time the app runs I have the expectation that the bool will not exist, since I have just reinstalled the app. I expect from the documentation that boolForKey will therefore return NO.

I am seeing the opposite though. boolForKey is returning YES, which fubars my initial user settings. Any idea why this might be happening or a good way around it?

```
BOOL stopAutoLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"StopAutoLogin"];
_userWantsAutoLogin = !stopAutoLogin;
```

So stopAutoLogin comes out as "YES", which is completely unexpected.

Stranger and stranger: When I call objectForKey:@"StopAutoLogin" I get a nil object, as expected. It's just the boolForKey that returns a bad value. So I changed the code to this:

```
// this is nil
NSObject *wrapper = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StopAutoLogin"];

// this is YES
BOOL stopAutoLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"StopAutoLogin"];
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Agree with Rits.  Also: When you say "the device", do you mean your phone, or the simulator?  Instead of "deleting the app" as you would on the phone, go to the menu and select "Reset Content and Settings...".

Comment: I mean on the phone. I delete the app, make sure it's gone from the task bar, then cable load it with the Xcode debugger.

Comment: And did you try "Reset Contents and Settings" like phooze suggested? And ofcourse doublecheck you aren't actually setting StopAutoLogin to YES before you read out the value.

Comment: I think Reset Content and Settings is for the simulator right? Is there an analogue for the device? And yeah, I checked everywhere for the key and set breakpoints everywhere it is mentioned, to no avail.

Comment: So this occurs on the device only? On the simulator, everything is working as expected?

Comment: @MahatmaManic I am having the same problem. Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

please try [UserDefaults synchronize];

Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

please see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you register the default values for your keys?

```
NSMutableDictionary *appDefaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
[appDefaults setObject:@"NO" forKey:kReloadOnStartKey];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

> If there is no registration domain,
>   one is created using the specified
>   dictionary, and NSRegistrationDomain
>   is added to the end of the search
>   list.
>
> The contents of the registration
>   domain are not written to disk; you
>   need to call this method each time
>   your application starts. You can place
>   a plist file in the application's
>   Resources directory and call
>   registerDefaults: with the contents
>   that you read in from that file.

See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: I haven't done that, but the same link you pasted claims that boolForKey should return NO when the key doesn't exist. Given the documentation, and the fact that objectForKey returns nil, why would boolForKey be returning YES?